# fluentd add fields and output by json

Tags: record, fluentd, transformer-model

I want to transform with fluentd something like this

```
{
  "source_app":"client",
  "location":"cn"
}
```

To this:

```
{
  "message":
  {
    "source_app":"client",
    "location":"cn"
  }
}
```

My fluentd config is:

```
<filter **>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby true
  auto_typecast true
  <record>
    message ${{"source_app"=>"${record["source_app"]}","location"=>"${record["location"]}"}}
  </record>
  remove_keys source_app,location
</filter>
<match **>
    @type stdout
</match>
```

But the result is：

```
{"message":"{\"source_app\"=>\"client\", \"location\"=>\"cn\"}"}
```

the result is not json type. why? how to config fluentd to make my result as json type?

Comment: Look at stdout's `output_type json`: https://docs.fluentd.org/formatter/stdout#example.

Comment: @Azeem  I change my config  ```<match **>
  @type stdout
  <format>
    @type stdout
    output_type json
  </format> </match>
```    but it not work

Comment: Can you please add the startup logs of fluentd along with these stdout prints?